# Having multiple A records to get forward rDNS to work

Tags: ubuntu, email-server, reverse-dns

Running a Droplet on DigitalOcean with Apache and a mailserver on Ubuntu. I've managed to get SPF, DKIM and DMARC working on this server, but Reverse DNS is something that I've never figured out.

I have a floating IP that points to this particular server, as it makes things easy when I want to change the Droplet that is serving my website. The DNS records are as follows:

```
A: example.com -> 1.2.3.4 (floating IP)
A: mail.example.com -> 5.6.7.8 (actual Droplet IP)
MX: mail.example.com
```

The problem with reverse DNS now is that a query to `5.6.7.8` leads to `example.com`, but a query of `example.com` leads to IP `1.2.3.4`, so reverse DNS (and PTR records, which I have no idea what they are) fails. Can I add an extra `A` record to my DNS to fix this?

```
A: example.com -> 5.6.7.8 (actual Droplet IP)
```

I presume this will cause DNS to either point to my floating IP or my actual Droplet, and that when the actual Droplet is down (e.g. when I want to switch the Droplet to assign to the floating IP), the floating IP will be used as the A record instead.

Comment: You need to fix the `PTR` record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like digital ocean doesn't support PTR records on floating IPs at this time;

https://ideas.digitalocean.com/ideas/DO-I-1023